# python generating random lists of defined length

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that generates a list of ten random integers from 1-5 inclusive, then prints the number each time each integer repeats.  Then prints a second list with the duplicates removed.  Right now I'm having an issue even getting the first list to generate at all.  I keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

This is what I have so far:

```
def randomTen():
    """return list of ten integers and the number of times each one
    appears"""
    firstList= []
    for num in range(1,11):
        x= int(random.randint(1,6))
        list1= firstList.append(x)
    print(list1)
```

Comment: You want `append`, not `extend`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed that, but now it just returns 'None'

Comment: Yes, this is how append() works. It changes the source list ("firstList") and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Additionally, your function will continue to return `None` until you return something with the `return` keyword.

Comment: That said, a list comprehension like `firstList = [random.randint(1,6) for num in range(10)]` is a more "pythonic" way to do the same.

Comment: Just to keep things tidy, randint() returns an int - there is no reason to cast it to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that this could be done more easily with a list comprehension:

```
firstList = [random.randint(1,6) for num in range(1, 11)]
```

As for your function, you needed to do:

```
firstList= []
for num in range(1,11):
    x= int(random.randint(1,6))
    firstList.append(x)
print(firstList)
```

`append` doesn't return anything, it changes the list in place.

Comment: Shouldn't `randint(1,6)` be `randint(1,5)`? From the OP: "*a list of ten random integers from 1-5 inclusive*"

Comment: @Robᵩ: I was following the OP's lead, but you are certainly correct!

Answer (score 1):

```
def randomTen():
    """return list of ten integers and the number of times each one
    appears"""
    firstList= []
    for num in range(1,11):
        x= int(random.randint(1,6))
        firstList.append(x)
    return firstList
```

You create an empty list firstList, append elements to it, and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

1) x is an integer, not a list. So just use

```
list1 = firstList.append(x)
```

2) If you want to remove replicates, you may just want to convert the list to a set :

```
print(set(list1))
```